# formula for f*$\omega$

Tags: analysis

I have the following problem:

> Let $U,V\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be open subsets, $f:U \rightarrow V$ a diffeomorphism and $\omega \in \Omega^nV$. Find a formula for $f^*\omega$.

My problem is that I don't know the meaning of $f^*\omega$.

$\Omega^nV$ is a vector space of k-forms, which are continuously differentiable once.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $\omega$ is something like a sum of terms of the form
$$g_1(y_1,y_2, \dots y_n)\wedge g_2(y_1,y_2, \dots y_n)\wedge \dots \wedge g_k(y_1,y_2, \dots y_n)$$

and given 
$$ f = (f_1(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), \dots f_n(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n))
$$
you just have $f^* \omega$ as a sum of terms of the form
$$g_1(f_1(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), \dots f_n(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n))\wedge g_2(f_1(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), \dots f_n(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n))\wedge \dots \wedge g_k(f_1(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), f_2(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n), \dots f_n(x_1,x_2, \dots x_n)).$$

That is, just substitute $\bf y$ in the image with $\bf f (\bf x)$

Comment: Does that mean, your answer is already the solution to my problem? Because I'm not sure, if I understand it completely. Is it possible for you to elaborate?
For example what eactly is the meaning of ∧?
Because we`ve never written it down like that.

Comment: @Tobi92sr What notation have you used for forms?

Comment: @Tobi92sr sorry for being late. $\wedge$ is just the antisymmetric product of forms, that is $dx \wedge dy = - dy \wedge dx$. So if $x = wz- z^2$ and $y= w^2$ then $dx \wedge dy $ becomes $(zdw +(w -2z)dz) \wedge 2wdw 
 = (4wz - 2w^2)dw \wedge dz $

Answer (score 1):

$f^*\omega$ is the pull-back of $\omega$. If $f: U \to V$ and $\omega$ is a differential form on $V$ then $f^*\omega$ is a differential form on $U$. How do we define this differential form on $U$? Given tangent vectors $u_1,\ldots,u_k$ we define $(f^*\omega)(u_1,\ldots,u_k)=\omega(f_*u_1,\ldots,f_*u_k)$, where $f_* : TU \to TV$ is the differential of $f$. The differential is a linear map whose matrix representation is the Jacobian matrix.

Calculate the Jacobian matrix. Apply the Jacobian matrix to each of the $u_i$ to give $f_*u_i$. Then apply the differential form $\omega$ on the $f_*u_i$.

Comment: Do you have any generic definition of *pull-back*? It's easy to find formulas for different types of object, but not a generic definition.

Comment: @md2perpe What do you mean by "generic"? My post works for manifolds $M$ and $N$ and differential $k$-forms. Wikipedia says you can generalise to certain types of tensor field: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_(differential_geometry)#Pullback_of_.28covariant.29_tensor_fields
but I don't have any experience of anything other than differential forms.

Comment: The Wikipedia page defines the pullback for several types of objects: smooth functions, bundles and sections, multilinear forms, cotangent vectors, tensor fields, differential forms. I'm looking for a unifying definition of pullbacks, or at least a description of what a pullback does, no matter what type of object it's working on.

Comment: @md2perpe Perhaps you should post a question of your own. That would get more attention.